# How to display a modal without using the onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

I would like to know how I can open a modal without clicking on a button. Basically if a user searches for something and the search does not return an results I would like a modal to popup informing the user that the search did not yield any results. I have pasted my code below but I dont think I am supposed to be calling jquery from within html.

```
  <table id="tableData" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>

            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                MobileNumber
            </th>

            <th>
                EmailAddress
            </th>

            <th>
                Identification Number
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            if(Model.Count == 0)
            {
                 $('#myConfirmationModal').modal('show');

                //alert("no results find");
            }
            <tr>

                <td>

                    <a class="anchorDetail" href="javascript:;" data-id=@item.ClientId>@item.FirstName</a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileNumber)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdentificationNumber)
                </td>



            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: use a dialog element and open attribute once no result is fetched!

Comment: <dialog open></dialog>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to execute `$(#....).modal('show')` after the page is loaded if the `count` is `0`. Execute the code inside `$(function(){...})`. JQuery will make sure to execute the function inside `$(...)` after document is loaded i.e. same as `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Try below.

```
if(Model.Count == 0) {
     <script>
        $(function() {
            {
                 $('#myConfirmationModal').modal('show');

                //alert("no results find");
            }
        });
     </script>
} else {
     @foreach (var item in Model) {
     ...
     ...
}
```